# Need advice on speeding up the python code on data cleaning

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, data-analysis, data-science

I'm running a side data analysis project using python notebook (jupyter). The dataset has ~1.3 rows, and the first thing I want to do it to extract day, month and year from the 'date' column in datasets. The code I wrote executes well except it takes really long time. I estimated it could take an hour and half to finish the data processing procedure. And I'm wondering if anyone can give some suggestions on my code to improve speed?

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def date_split(calendar):
    new_calendar={}
    i=0
    calendar_total=pd.DataFrame()
    num=calendar.shape[0]-1
    while i<=10000:

        tem=calendar_data.iloc[i,1]
        #extract year&month&day from day column
        listdate=datetime.strptime(tem,'%Y-%m-%d')
        new_calendar['Year']=listdate.year
        new_calendar['Month']=listdate.month
        new_calendar['Date']=listdate.day
        # add the other columns
        new_calendar['listId']=calendar.iloc[i,0]
        new_calendar['available']=calendar.iloc[i,2]
        new_calendar['price']=calendar.iloc[i,3]
        new_calendar=pd.DataFrame.from_records(new_calendar,index=[i])
        #change new_calendar data type from dic to pd dataframe        
        calendar_total=calendar_total.append(new_calendar)
        i=i+1

     return calendar_total
```

Again the goal is to extract year/month/day from 'day' column and make them into a new dataframe. Also does running the code in python locally speed up things significantly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you identified any particular bottleneck in your code through profiling etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would extract the year, month, and day from an existing dataframe into a new dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.date_range("19970202", periods=365*20)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year' : df['date'].dt.year, 'month' : df['date'].dt.month, 'day' : df['date'].dt.day})

print (df)
print (df2)
```

I haven't tested this for a big dataset yet (1.3 million rows?), but maybe this gives you a speedup.

Comment: Hi Johannesmik,
Thanks for the solution. However, in my case, I need to break the original data into a datetime-like object before i can use your method. The date I have in my dataframe is like "2007-10-09", I'm using strptime function to break them, and it does take really long for python to go through 1.3 million rows. Feel free to share your thoughts, anyway, thanks for your insights, really helpful :)

Comment: What takes long in your code is the 1million appends.

You can also convert a string column like "2007-10-09" to a datetime column using pd.to_datetime.

For example you can create a temporary dataframe holding datetime values like this:

```df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : df['A'], 'B' : pd.to_datetime(df['B']), 'c' : df['C']})``` (where df['B'] holds strings in a date format.) And then you can use code similar to my answer to create a dataframe holding rows for the month, day, etc

Comment: Indeed I believe the append takes really long time. Later I found out using the pandas in-buit function to_datetime really helps. I used following code to extract year value:split['year']=pd.to_datetime(calendar_data['date']).dt.year. It took <30s to give me results. Anyway, thanks a lot for pointing out the bottleneck in my code, much appreciated:) .